# What is the meaning of "Sign up" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I found a strange meaning of sign up [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sign+up)
,It says that sign up is to enlist, like in military.

Also I found this "Sign up" **in business domain**:

> By signing up early adopters (i.e. those quickest to adopt or most influential in your space) you can make it near impossible for new entrants to get any foothold

Have I figured it correctly? is it means to enlist customers?

Can it be that all sites around are saying "sign up" in that sense?

Comment: You probably meant "customers", not "costurmers".  To *sign* somebody *up* is to find somebody and get into an agreement with them.  Such agreement can be written or, in case of software, EULA (end-user license agreement) which exists between the creator of the software and its user if the user starts using the software after "agreeing" to EULA by performing some act (like clicking on the "Agree" button or something like that).

Comment: @VictorBazarov Pls don't answer in comments.

Comment: @Victor Bazarov costumers! wow first time to encounter such word,thanks.
by the way, you probably meant "costumers" not "costurmers" :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got it.

To **sign** *somebody* **up** is to find somebody and get into an agreement with them.

Comment: So you see it works both ways . You can say you  "sign up" customers or that they "sign up".  The first is a _transitive_ usage, the second _intransitive_.  Exactly the same is true of the synonym you mentioned—"enlist.  You say they "enlisted" customers (transitive), but the customers "enlisted" (intransitive).